# php simplexml_load_string fails - codification issue

Tags: php, xml, utf

Im driving crazy, tried hundreds of solutions and any worked for me, and it looks weird because I think that my situation is similar to everbody ho had problem with encoding but, as I said, no solution works. Here is the Deal:

I call a Webservice (coded with Windev) and I get a valid xml string using `file_get_contents($url)` to check the encoding of my string I do the following:

```
$str = file_get_contents($url);
echo mb_detect_encoding($str);
echo "$str";
```

and I get this output:

```
ASCII 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<clientesPresentes><cliente><numCliente>109495</numCliente><nombre>MARIA ÁNGELA</nombre><apellidos>APELLIDO</apellidos><imagen></imagen><parcela>BBQ-100001</parcela><pais>Estonia</pais></cliente><totalClientesPresentes>1</totalClientesPresentes></clientesPresentes>
```

As far as I know ASCII is the same as UTF-8 codification, so I think thats fine.

The problem is that my xml will have accented characters like the example above and special characters like 'ñ' (spanish).

when I try to do the `simplexml_load_string($str)` with that xml string (with `ÁNGELA`) I get a false from the function, the same string with `ANGELA` works just fine.

any idea on how to solve this, codification, escape especial characters ... whatever, help please !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: UTF-8 and ASCII are not interchangable. Only the first 128 characters of ASCII (i.e. ASCII-7) are encoded the same way in utf-8. `Á` is not in ASCII-7.

Comment: wheres your code accessing maria? here it works fine. [link](http://codepad.viper-7.com/BMb5IB)